# OUTLOOK re-interpreting "plain text" properly

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, office365

I was wondering if anybody had an answer to this question of getting the output of Write-Host into the body of an email. I learned that Write-Host only displays onto the console so that won't work. for now I am stuck and am in need of some direction. Here is what I have so far.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicyunrestricted

$computerSystem = Get-CimInstance CIM_ComputerSystem
$computerBIOS = Get-CimInstance CIM_BIOSElement
$computerOS = Get-CimInstance CIM_OperatingSystem
$computerCPU = Get-CimInstance CIM_Processor
$computerHDD = Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID = 'C:'"
$computerip = Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip
Clear-Host


$Body = @(
"System Information for: " + $computerSystem.Name
"Manufacturer: " + $computerSystem.Manufacturer
"Model: " + $computerSystem.Model
"Serial Number: " + $computerBIOS.SerialNumber
"CPU: " + $computerCPU.Name
"HDD Capacity: "  + "{0:N2}" -f ($computerHDD.Size/1GB) + "GB"
"HDD Space: " + "{0:P2}" -f ($computerHDD.FreeSpace/$computerHDD.Size) + " 
Free 
(" + "{0:N2}" -f ($computerHDD.FreeSpace/1GB) + "GB)"
"RAM: " + "{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB) + "GB"
"Operating System: " + $computerOS.caption + ", Service Pack: " + 
$computerOS.ServicePackMajorVersion
"IP Address:" + $computerip
"User logged In: " + $computerSystem.UserName 
"Last Reboot: " + $computerOS.LastBootUpTime
) -join "`r`n  `n"
write-host $body


$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “password” -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 
(“support@email”, $secpasswd)

Send-MailMessage -To "support@email.com" -SmtpServer "smtp.office365.com" -
Credential $mycreds -UseSsl "Backup Notification" -Port "587" -Body $body -
From "support@email.com" -BodyAsHtml
```

So far this works, I just need to clean up the output a bit. I think this is a problem with OUTLOOK re-interpreting "plain text" properly - as outlook tries to 'think' for you and removes line breaks that it thinks are excessive.

the email output looks like this:

System Information for: APL-PBC4Y9W Manufacturer: LENOVO Model: 2349OK7 Serial Number: PBC4Y9W CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz HDD Capacity: 298.09GB HDD Space: 57.68 % Free (171.93GB) RAM: 7.70GB Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Professional , Service Pack: 1 IP Address:111.111.11.1 User logged In: GEINDSYS-AMER\502706436 Last Reboot: 04/26/2017 08:22:07

I am hoping to have every item on a new line.

Comment: No - it's because you throw a bunch of plain text into an HTML email - remove the `-BodyAsHtml` switch

Comment: Thanks, problem solved.